# How to evaluate boolean like variable in bash in flexible way?

Tags: bash

What is the portable way to evaluate a variable in bash as true regardless the way is defined.

Assuming we would use DEBUG name for the variable, this would be the evaluation logic:

- if not defined, assume false (script should also run with `set -ueo pipefail` mode)
- if `0`, False, FALSE, false, no -> false
- if defined and not case above assume true

A slight deviation from the spec above would be acceptable but the idea is the same, to give the user some flexibility regarding how he defines it, and avoid a execution failure due "unexpected input".

Extra kudos if someone find a clean way to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

Set a reasonable default value for the variable:

```
DEBUG="${DEBUG:-0}"
```

Then, in your code, check:

```
if [ "${DEBUG}" -ne 0 ] ; then
    echo "DEBUG: foo ..."
fi
```

Further read: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: Why I have the impression that this will fail to work if user defines `DEBUG=true` ?

Comment: It won't, but I don't recommend trying to be that flexible in shell. Just require the value be set to 0 or 1. The undefined default of 0 is fine.

Comment: The alternative is to use a `case` statement to explicitly match any of the valid values you have in mind.

Comment: @chepner I was about to suggest that, but I think it just adds complexity for no reason. I mean what is the benefit of using `False` over `0`  or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't recommend getting too flexible with the values you allow, I would use a `case` statement to match the allowed values explicitly, and raise an error for any other values.

```
DEBUG=${DEBUG:-0}  # As suggested by hek2mgl

shopt -s nocasematch  # Ignore the case of the value
case $DEBUG in
    0|false|no)
      echo "DEBUG is false"
      ;;
    1|true|yes)
      echo "DEBUG is true"
      ;;
    *)
      echo "Invalid setting for DEBUG: $DEBUG"
      exit 1
      ;;
esac
```

Comment: Usually any of your posts is worth an upvote. Don't bear with me in this case. I just think that this flexibility adds no real value, only *potential* bugs.

Comment: I'm not a fan of the flexibility either. My goal, however, is to *explicitly* accept a set of values, for either true or false, and reject any other value, instead of "defaulting" an unrecognized value to either true or false. I would recommend limiting `DEBUG` to either 0 or 1, with the small allowance of treating an unset or empty value as 0.